# Can't do POST request on C# to blockr.io

Tags: c#, bitcoin

Trying to write a method to push a TX, I never programatically done a POST request, so I'm clearly messing somewhere bad.

According to the documentation from blockr, I'm supposed to do this:

> To publish a transaction make a POST (!) request with your transaction
>   hex to the push API.
>
> Using curl this would be like (shell example):
>
> `curl -d '{"hex":"TX_HASH"}' http://btc.blockr.io/api/v1/tx/push`

I'm getting 500 errors left and right.

I'm doing this on C#, could someone help?

```
Post("http://btc.blockr.io/api/v1/tx/push", "hex", HexString);


    public static void Post(string RequestURL, string Post1, string Post2)
    {
        using (var wb = new WebClient())
        {
            var data = new NameValueCollection();
            data[Post1] = Post2;
            var response = wb.UploadValues(RequestURL, "POST", data);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default UploadValues doesn't format the data in json, you could format it yourself:

```
public static void Post(string RequestURL, string Post1, string Post2)
{
    using (var wb = new WebClient())
    {
        var data = string.Format("{0}\"{1}\":\"{2}\"{3}", "{", Post1, Post2, "}");
        var response = wb.UploadString(RequestURL, "POST", data);
    }
}
```

Or use a JSON serializer such as NewtonSoft

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick reply.
I'm getting this string on the POST:
**"{\"hex\":\"01000000....(continued)\"}"**

Should work from what I gather, but it's still failing with 500 errors, on this and some other sites with similar formats.

Example, python code for another site:

    `return make_request('https://blockchain.info/pushtx', 'tx='+tx)`

I tried formatting the string as `var data = Post1 + Post2;`, still getting 500 errors.

Comment: It could be a difference in the way the data is sent, or the headers. You could try using a tool such as Fiddler (http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to see what is being sent to the server in each case.